# How are mappings determined in new indices in elaticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am adding a new field through logstash like so:

```
 if [message] =~ /.+SLOW QUERY/ {
    grok {
        match => ["message", "SLOW QUERY.+%{NUMBER:slow_query:double}ms"]
    }
 }
```

But the field is created with the type string.

***GET indexName/_mapping*** output

```
      "slow_query": {
        "type": "text",
        "norms": false,
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
```

To get around this I reindexed the data into a new index with the correct data type (double), but the next day (indices are automatically created daily) the index that was created contained a string data type.

***Note:*** elasticsearc.yml has no settings(aside from cluster/node names), all default

- How are mappings determined in new indices in elaticsearch?
- How can I force new indices to take the correct data type (double) for the slow_query field?
- Is there some sort of index templating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take control of the mapping for that specific set of indices by defining an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/indices-templates.html) inside Elasticsearch.

Starting from the [default template Logstash is using for ES 5.x indices](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/v7.3.1/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template-es5x.json) I have used most of it and added your `slow_query` explicitly there as `double`. Next day when Logstash will create another index with that template name `my_daily_indices_name-*` Elasticsearch will see it's matching this template and use the definition to create the index and enforce `slow_query` as `double`.

```
PUT /_template/my_template
{
  "template": "my_daily_indices_name-*",
    "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
      "_all" : {"enabled" : true, "norms" : false},
      "dynamic_templates" : [ {
        "message_field" : {
          "path_match" : "message",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "norms" : false
          }
        }
      }, {
        "string_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "text", "norms" : false,
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : { "type": "keyword" }
            }
          }
        }
      } ],
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp": { "type": "date", "include_in_all": false },
        "@version": { "type": "keyword", "include_in_all": false },
        "geoip"  : {
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties" : {
            "ip": { "type": "ip" },
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" },
            "latitude" : { "type" : "half_float" },
            "longitude" : { "type" : "half_float" }
          }
        },
        "slow_query": {
          "type": "double"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```